# How do I change the default location of Sticky Notes on windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, path, sticky-notes

Looking for a solution to help me whenever add a note into sticky notes it will save on new location. Something that always windows check the new location to pull up the file not a copy/short-cut of

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\Sticky Notes\StickyNotes.snt
```

In other words I'd like to remove `%AppData%\Microsoft\Sticky Notes\StickyNotes.snt` and whenever start the Sticky Notes, 
see the file in this location: `e:\Notes\StickeyNotes.snt`

I've tried this one as administrator:

```
mklink /H "%AppData%\Microsoft\Sticky Notes\StickyNotes.snt" "e:\Notes\StickeyNotes.snt"
```

and even this:

```
mklink "e:\Notes\StickeyNotes.snt" "%AppData%\Microsoft\Sticky Notes\StickyNotes.snt"
```

I had a quick look in the registry but couldn't see any pointers there.

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked using /J instead thus creating a directory junction for the whole directory, seeing as how the .snt file is probably the only file to ever reside in that directory. So try this:

```
mklink /J "%appdata%\Microsoft\Sticky Notes" "e:\Notes\StickeyNotes.snt"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to trick the OS to do this. The link below worked for me

[How to change the default location of Sticky Notes in windows](http://www.mytechnology.space/how-to-change-the-default-location-of-sticky-notes-in-windows/)

Here are the steps:

1. Copy the content of the folder from %AppData%\Microsoft\Sticky
   Notes\ to D:\StickyNotes
2. Delete Sticky Notes folder at
   %AppData%\Microsoft\Sticky Notes\
3. Create a symbolic link by running the below line in Command Prompt
   as administrator:

   Mklink /d "%appdata%\Microsoft\Sticky Notes\" "D:\StickyNotes\"

Comment: Welcome to Super User. External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.