# How change location of updated StickyNotes database (SQLite) On Windows 10 & Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, path, sticky-notes

I searched many places for change location of updated **StickyNotes** database (**SQLite**) On Windows 10 & Windows 11 with no help.
Now my goal is windows 11.
it seems it is not possible to change that location.
It is very important because i lost my notes several times cause of damage on C drive.
Is it possible to change that path?
Path is like below :

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState
```

Comment: `i lost my notes several times cause of damage on C drive` .. shouldn't that be your real concern?  This is not normal.  Do you intend on storing the file on a different drive?  You could simply move the folder and junction or hard link it back to the original location and not worry about configuring it's location.

Comment: Move which folder(s)? When i move database file StickyNotes can not run.    I just want to transfer this app to D driver with all it's related files. Also i could n't find a way for this transfer on registry.

Comment: Use an alternative: https://alternativeto.net/software/7-sticky-notes/ Microsoft store apps are different from regular Windows executables, and not easily modified. That said, if your C: drive is flaky, your worries are far greater then loss of notes.

Comment: I also tried to move db file & create a shortcut for it. StickyNotes can not run in this way too.

Comment: Not a shortcut, a hard link or junction (see the [mklink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink) command).  StickyNotes will not know the difference.  The folder I am referring to the `LocalState` folder or even `Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_8wekyb3d8bbwe`.   You might need to change permissions to mess with it and you will need to make sure StickyNotes is closed and not accessing the file to be able to do it.  If you do it correctly, it will indeed work.

Comment: That shortcut was created with mklink, But StickyNotes hanged after run. What kind of permission should i give to that shortcut?

Comment: Solved with this link https://superuser.com/questions/977475/how-do-i-change-the-default-location-of-sticky-notes-on-windows-7 Permission -> EveryOne = Write -> Thanks

Comment: Please write it as answer.

Comment: that makes your question a duplicate ... there is no reason to be posting an answer here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the default location of Sticky Notes on windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/977475/how-do-i-change-the-default-location-of-sticky-notes-on-windows-7)

Comment: Yes, But the point was Write Permission to EveryOne on that shortcut. Write it as your answer and let me accept it.

Comment: Windows 10 changed the default Sticky Notes location. I do not believe this marked duplicate is duplicate.